# Pullbacks of $C^*$-algebras

Tags: ct.category-theory, oa.operator-algebras

I am reading the paper of Pedersen: "Pullback and Pushout Constructions in C^*-Algebra Theory". I try to work out the arguments from Proposition $3.1$ of his paper (you can find this article in the world wide web). In particular the implication: "if pullback diagram then the three conditions hold. I know how to construct $\sigma:X\rightarrow A\oplus_CB$ and that by pullback property we get an unique arrow $\chi:A\oplus_CB\rightarrow X$. I can also prove that $\chi\circ\sigma=Id$ but with the other composition $\sigma\circ\chi=Id$ i have problems, because i have to show that this is true to conclude that $\sigma$ is an $*$-isomorphism. Someone an idea? Pedersen concludes that from this properties (i) and (ii) follows directly. Can you explain me how this follows from the fact that $\sigma$ is an isomorphism?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The world wide web is a big place. Does this paper have a URL?

Comment: I suppose that the paper at http://www.math.ru.nl/~mueger/ped2.pdf is meant.

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123699934560 or download it here :)

Comment: Isn't this a consequence of the fact that $A \oplus_C B$ satisfies the universal property of a pullback and pullbacks are unique up to isomorphism or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yeah yoo're right that pullbacks are unique up to isomorphism, but therefore you have to show that there is $A\oplus_CB$ is a pullback and therefore you have to make a same kind of argumentation, isn't it?

Comment: But $A \oplus_C B$ consists of those pairs $(a,b)$, which map to the same element in $C$. So, if I map some $Y$ into $A$ and $B$ in such a way that their images in $C$ agree, then by definition it factors over a map $Y \to A \oplus_C B$. This is the pullback property. Pedersen already writes on page 247, where he defines pullbacks that such a pullback is isomorphic to the restricted direct sum.

Comment: Okay :) i think i want to prove precisely that $X$ and $A\oplus_CB$ are isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

Both $\mathrm{id}$  and $\sigma\circ\chi$ map from $A \oplus_C B$ to  $A \oplus_C B$ respecting the left and right projection maps.  (I leave to the reader the writing out of the diagrams.)  Since  $A \oplus_C B$ has the pull-back property, these maps must be equal.